Does the following sentence make sense or is the word "yet” redundant?

We’ve reached out to a rep for Payne as well as Scottsdale prosecutors for comment, but so far, no word back yet.

Is the word "yet” redundant?

If you apply the fresh fish sold here principle then probably all of "for comment, but so far, no word back yet" is redundant because it can all be inferred from what came before (if there was a response, they would state it, and what else would they have reached out for?) On the other hand, repetition can be used for emphasis or to give a folksy character to writing.

Yes, it is redundant, but redundancy in speech is not necessarily a flaw.  The idea is reinforced.
